# Add a span in a span with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to put a `<span>` in an other `<span>` in the title of JQuery's modal but it doesn't work.

Here's my HTML code :

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar...">
  <span class="ui-dialog-title">Info title</span>
  ...
</div>
<div id="1">
```

And I want to put a `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>` inside the `ui-dialog-title` `<span>`.

I tried to do it like this :

```
$(".ui-dialog-title").prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>');
```

And it works !

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar...">
  <span class="ui-dialog-title">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>Info title
  </span>
  ...
</div>
<div id="1">
```

**But**, I will have **multiple** `<span>` with the class `ui-dialog-title` in my document and I want to access this `<span>` using the id of the next `<div>`.

I tried this :

`$("#"+myId).prev("div").first("span").prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>');`

But the glyphicon `<span>` was placed BEFORE ui-dialog-title `<span>` :

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar...">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
  <span class="ui-dialog-title">Info title</span>
  ...
</div>
<div id="1">
```

I don't understand why it is placed here because with the other method, it works.

I hope you will understand my problem and thank you for your help !

Comment: try to use append() instead of prepend()

Comment: try not to have ids as numbers, bad practice

Comment: I put numbers as id just for the post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#"+myId).prev("div").find(".ui-dialog-title").prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>');
```

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mh9E6eZXDrnuCwTGNPOD)

Structure:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar">
  <span class="ui-dialog-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>Info title</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent so much time in this!! I'll accept you answer as soon as I can!